# Debian apache2 restart fault after some updates

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, python

Can anyone give me an advice with this please?

I run update on my debian server by Webmin. After updating some apache2 and etc, it shows update fail.

After that I can't start apache2. I must run

```
netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

then

```
kill -9 1047
```

and now I can start apache2.

When I started it first time after update, some websites on fastCGI won't work. I must change them in ISPconfig3 to mod-PHP, and now works.

Now I can't even restart apache without kill pid.

In log of ISP I see this:

```
Unable to open logs
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80   
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
 no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

In log of some website I see this:

```
[emerg] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: can´t lock process table in pid 19264
```

---

Do you think it will be solution to update everything by:

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get upgrade
```

to complete all updates? I have little scare if I do that then next errors will occur.

---

If I look at apache log I see the following error:

```
Debian Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.5+', found '2.6.6'
```

But that was there before that problem before.

Comment: Using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` should be safe, because it will show you what it will do and asks if you want to continue. If this doesn't help, I would try a `apt-get install --reinstall apache2`. Note that none of these commands are without risk, so backup first.

Comment: [RESOLVED] I just do that apt-get update && apt-get upgrade and than was OK.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify some points,

- Don't use `kill -9` to stop a process unless you really have no other choice like it is not responding at all. It may cause data loss/corruption. Instead, you can use the script `/etc/init.d/apache2` for your case
- Doing `apt-get update` and `apt-upgrade` will provide you with the available patches and updates from debian which are mostly bug fixes and security patches.

The `unable to open logs` error may indicate a permission problem. Check your log files permissions and make you are starting apache with `sudo`.

The `could not bind to address` error indicates that the port is already reserved for other process. You can verify using `netstat -lnp`.

Comment: kill -9 I must use because /etc/init.d/apache2 stop dont stop it

Comment: Doing apt-get update and apt-upgrade - I dont shure if I can run it before I fix this mess:(

Comment: I starting apache as root

Answer (score 1):

The error you give...

```
[emerg] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: can´t lock process table in pid
```

...is covered in this apache bug that states its due to an incompatibility between certain versions of mpm-itk and mod_fcgid.

It will be displayed every time the server serves up a fastcgi page, usually PHP. The server will still deliver static content in this state.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55350

The bug is not fixed yet, so current solutions are switch to mpm-prefork or change to using non-fastcgi. For PHP switch to using mod-php.

On a Debian/Ubuntu system you can switch to mpm-prefork simply by running

`apt-get remove apache2-mpm-itk`

Debian switches over itself:

```
root@vps1:/var/lib/apache2/fcgid# apt-get remove apache2-mpm-itk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-mpm-itk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,358 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Get:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main apache2-mpm-prefork amd64 2.2.22-13+deb7u2 [2,358 B]
Fetched 2,358 B in 0s (7,481 B/s)                
dpkg: apache2-mpm-itk: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2-mpm-prefork (>> 2.0.52) | apache2-mpm-itk; however:
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is to be removed.
 apache2 depends on apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u2) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u2) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u2) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u2); however:
  Package apache2-mpm-worker is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-event is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is to be removed.

(Reading database ... 48579 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2-mpm-itk ...
[ ok ] Stopping web server: apache2 ... waiting .
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-mpm-prefork.
(Reading database ... 48583 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2-mpm-prefork (from .../apache2-mpm-prefork_2.2.22-13+deb7u2_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up apache2-mpm-prefork (2.2.22-13+deb7u2) ...
[ ok ] Starting web server: apache2.
```